# Is there an 'intrinsic' characterization of the usual topology on a finite-dimensional vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ denote a finite-dimensional vector space. Then $V$ becomes a topological space in a canonical way, by choosing a basis and using this to get an isomorphism to Euclidean space. It turns out that the topology you get is independent of choice of basis, so this makes $V$ into a topological vector space in a canonical way.

> **Question.** Is there a more intrinsic, or abstract, or basis-free approach to characterizing this topology, that gets closer to the heart of why it's important?

Comment: Isn't it just the smallest topology, such that all elements of $V^*$ are continuous?

Comment: By the way you should add that you work over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ and fix the usual topology on the base field.

Comment: @MooS, woah nice idea! Arguably you're right about $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. However for me the notion of a "vector space over a field" is a bit unnecessary because they're just modules. So I tend to use vector space to mean $\mathbb{R}$-module. If I'm working over anything other than $\mathbb{R}$, I just start saying $R$-module or $k$-module or whatever.

Comment: To prove it, the only thing you have to do is check it for the case $V=\mathbb R^n$, i.e. you have to check whether all inverse images of open sets in $\mathbb R$ w.r.t. linear maps $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ generate the euclidean topology.

Comment: @MooS, just a thought, but perhaps the fact that every closed convex set is an intersection of halfspaces is relevant.

Comment: This topology is unique. If you have a finite dimensional TVS then there is [only one topology which is Hausdorff](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/).

Comment: Nice, this seems pretty intrinsic to me :) And this of course also automatically proves my claim that you can define this topology by saying that linear functionals are continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many characterizations of the usual topology on $V$ that do not involve a choice of a basis.  Probably the most important is:

- The usual topology on $V$ is the unique topology that makes $V$ a  topological vector space.  That is, it is the unique $T_0$ topology that makes addition $V\times V\to V$ and scalar multiplication $\mathbb{R}\times V\to V$ continuous.

This is a standard theorem in functional analysis.  See [How to endow topology on a finite dimensional topological vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445547/how-to-endow-topology-on-a-finite-dimensional-topological-vector-space), for instance.

Here are some other characterizations.  The proofs are easy and I leave them for you to discover.

- The usual topology on $V$ is the coarsest topology that makes all linear maps $V\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous.
- The usual topology on $V$ is the coarsest topology that makes all linear maps $V\to \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
- The usual topology on $V$ is the finest topology that makes all linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n\to V$ continuous for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Note that the "dual" of the first of these three is not correct: the usual topology on $V$ is *not* the finest topology on $V$ that makes all linear maps $\mathbb{R}\to V$ (or even all affine maps $\mathbb{R}\to V$) continuous, at least not if $\dim V>1$.  Indeed, as every multivariable calculus student learns, there are functions $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ whose restrictions to any line are continuous but which are not continuous.

Comment: The linked answer proves your claim for the $T_2$ (and therefore $T_1$) case, but not $T_0$. So I asked a question about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529585/proof-that-the-standard-topology-is-the-only-t-0-one-that-makes-mathbb-rn).