# Why the unitary group of finite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ is compact in the SOT of $B(H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, and $U$ be its unitary group.
Let $B(H)$ be the space of all bounded linear operators on $H$.

Why $U$ is compact in the SOT(strong operator topology) of $B(H)$?

In Heine-Borel theorem, for a subset $S$ of $R^n$, $S$ is compact (in norm topology) if and only if it is closed and bounded. However, now $U$ is in the SOT (not norm topology) of $B(H)$. Can I still use Heine-Borel thm to prove it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: SOT topology is normed on a finite dimensional space. Infact all Hausdorff topologies on finite dimensional vectorspaces are equivalent.

Comment: @s.harp Thank you so much, but may I ask where I can find such conclusion, or can you explain more why all Hausdorff topologies on finite-dimensional vector spaces are equivalent?

Comment: These lecture notes seem to be about the result: http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~infusino/Lect8.pdf Also this answer from Daniel Fischer on this website is good: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445547/how-to-endow-topology-on-a-finite-dimensional-topological-vector-space